# Is it possible to install a custom CA certificate without the ca-certificates package on Debian?

Tags: debian, certificates

Is it possible to install a custom ca certificate on Debian without installing the `ca-certificate` package?

I tend to run my servers beyond the lifespan of each release, and I always seem to have problems after a few years. Simple problems, like cURL not being able to verify the legitimacy of the server, PHP's `openssl.cafile` and `curl.cainfo`, etc. Nothing devastating, but annoying.

I'm installing Buster now and want to avoid any problems from the start this time.

Ideally I'd like to download [cacert.pem](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) from curl.se (Mozilla source), put it in a directory, then tell the OS and any software that asks for it to use it. That way, when it expires I can just re-download the latest from curl.se or the Mozilla source.

Comment: An useful command to handle custom certs is update-ca-certificates part of... ca-certificates.

Comment: Every answer I found searching led straight to `update-ca-certificates`, which is a part of the ca-certificates package. That's why I asked this question so specifically. Some linux guru has to know how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`update-ca-certificates` is actually a shell script. You could just read it and adapt parts of it to your needs.

In a nutshell: when `update-ca-certificates` adds a certificate, it creates a symbolic link to `/etc/ssl/certs/` pointing to the PEM-formatted certificate file. `update-ca-certificates` expects the CA certficate to be in a PEM formatted file with a `*.crt` suffix, and the link name will have that suffix changed to `*.pem` instead: so `/etc/ssl/certs/<somename>.pem` will be linked to `/elsewhere/<somename>.crt`.

OpenSSL requires that the directory containing trusted CA certificates has them accessible by their hashes, so within the `/etc/ssl/certs/` directory, another symbolic link will be created: `<certificate hash>.0 -> <somename>.pem`. The `<certificate hash>` can be calculated manually with:

```
openssl x509 -in <certificate PEM file> -noout -hash
```

If another certificate has the same hash, then the `.0` portion will be incremented to `.1`, then to `.2` etc. until an unique name can be found. This hashing is not a security mechanism: it just allows OpenSSL to find the required CA certificate quickly by its hash when validating certificates.

Alternatively, `cd /etc/ssl/certs; openssl rehash .` can be used to create hash symlinks for all certificates within that directory.

The contents of the new certificate PEM file will also be appended to `/etc/ssl/certificates/ca-certificates.crt`, for those programs that only accept their list of trusted CA certificates as a single file. If the PEM-formatted certificate is missing its trailing newline character, the script will add one automatically when appending the certificate to `ca-certificates.crt`.

The `update-ca-certificates` script will also run any scripts placed into `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/`.

In case you have any `.dpkg`-packaged version of Java installed, there will most likely be a script named `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore` dropped by the Java package, which will similarly update the Java keystore file at `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`, so that it will also contain the exact same certificates as the OpenSSL CA certificate directory `/etc/ssl/certs` or the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Edited

Answer (score 3):

- Copy `my_own_ca.crt` to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`
- run script `update-ca-certificates`

`update-ca-certificates` create necessary simlink and **update /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt** file. Linux utilities tools like `wget` or `curl` use this file as CA file as default.

Or find the switch that specifies the CA file or switch for disable check certificate. For wget it is:

- `wget --no-check-certificate` - for disable CA check
- `wget --ca-certificate=file` - Use file as the file with the bundle of certificate authorities ("CA") to verify the peers.  The certificates must be in PEM format.

**Example**

Copy your own ca with `crt` suffix to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# ls -alFh
celkem 16K
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4,0K úno  5 13:02 ./
drwxrwsr-x 7 root staff 4,0K kvě  7  2014 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 1,5K úno  5 13:02 thawte-Primary-Root-CA-G3.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 1,7K úno  5 13:01 thawte-SHA256-ssl-ca.crt
```

Run `update-ca-certificates`

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# update-ca-certificates 
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate thawte-Primary-Root-CA-G3.pem
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate thawte-Primary-Root-CA-G3.pem
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate thawte-primary-root.pem
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate thawte-primary-root.pem
2 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
```

Verify:

```
/etc/ssl/certs# ls -alFh | grep local
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   62 úno  5 13:03 thawte-Primary-Root-CA-G3.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/thawte-Primary-Root-CA-G3.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   57 úno  5 13:03 thawte-SHA256-ssl-ca.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/thawte-SHA256-ssl-ca.crt
```

```
/etc/ssl/certs# openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout

subject=/CN=ACEDICOM Root/OU=PKI/O=EDICOM/C=ES
issuer=/CN=ACEDICOM Root/OU=PKI/O=EDICOM/C=ES

subject=/C=CO/O=Sociedad Cameral de Certificaci\xC3\xB3n Digital - Certic\xC3\xA1mara S.A./CN=AC Ra\xC3\xADz Certic\xC3\xA1mara S.A.
issuer=/C=CO/O=Sociedad Cameral de Certificaci\xC3\xB3n Digital - Certic\xC3\xA1mara S.A./CN=AC Ra\xC3\xADz Certic\xC3\xA1mara S.A.

subject=/C=IT/L=Milan/O=Actalis S.p.A./03358520967/CN=Actalis Authentication Root CA
issuer=/C=IT/L=Milan/O=Actalis S.p.A./03358520967/CN=Actalis Authentication Root CA

subject=/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
issuer=/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root

...

Find your CA
```